# Custom Post Type Query by user id

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, users

I have a custom ajax function which queries all the custom post types on my site but I need to be able to sort it to query and display the posts by the user who created the post. I'm just wondering how do I edit this function to query by user ID.

Here is the function:

```
function stm_ajax_filter_profile() {

$user_id = $_GET["user_id"]; // name of hidden input

if(stm_is_listing() or stm_is_motorcycle()) {
    $get_title = stm_is_motorcycle();
} else {
    $get_title = false;
}
$stm_listing_filter = stm_get_filter($get_title);

$query             = $stm_listing_filter['listing_query'];
$response            = array();
$response['html']    = '';
$response['pagination']    = '';
$response['owner']     = $stm_listing_filter['owner'];
$response['url']     = $stm_listing_filter['url'];
$response['binding'] = $stm_listing_filter['binding'];
$response['badges']  = $stm_listing_filter['badges'];
$response['list_view_link']  = $stm_listing_filter['list_view_link'];
$response['grid_view_link']  = $stm_listing_filter['grid_view_link'];
$response['posts_per_page_link']  = $stm_listing_filter['posts_per_page_link'];

if(!empty($stm_listing_filter['title'])) {
    $response['title'] = $stm_listing_filter['title'];
}

if(isset($stm_listing_filter['total'])) {
    $response['total'] = $stm_listing_filter['total'];
}

if(!empty($stm_listing_filter['featured'])) {
    if ( $stm_listing_filter['featured']->have_posts() ):
        ob_start();
        while ( $stm_listing_filter['featured']->have_posts() ) {
            $stm_listing_filter['featured']->the_post();
            if(!empty($_GET['view_type']) and $_GET['view_type'] == 'grid'){
                if(stm_is_listing()){
                    get_template_part( 'partials/listing-cars/listing-grid-directory', 'loop' );
                } else {
                    get_template_part( 'partials/listing-cars/listing-grid', 'loop' );
                }
            } else {
                if(stm_is_listing()) {
                    get_template_part( 'partials/listing-cars/listing-grid-directory', 'loop' );
                } elseif(stm_is_boats()) {
                    get_template_part( 'partials/listing-cars/listing-grid-loop', 'boats' );
                } else {
                    get_template_part( 'partials/listing-cars/listing-grid', 'loop' );
                }
            }
        }
        $response['featured_html'] = ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
    endif;
}

if ( $query->have_posts() ):
    ob_start();

    $template = 'partials/listing-cars/listing-list-directory-loop';
    if(!empty($_GET['view_type']) and $_GET['view_type'] == 'grid') {

    $template = 'partials/listing-cars/listing-grid-directory-loop';

    } elseif(!empty($_GET['view_type']) and $_GET['view_type'] == 'map') {

    $template = 'partials/listing-cars/listing-map';

    } else {

    $template = 'partials/listing-cars/listing-list-directory-loop';

    }


    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        get_template_part($template);
    }

    $response['html'] = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    else:
    $response['html'] .= '<div class="row">';
    $response['html'] .= '<div class="col-md-12">';
    $response['html'] .= '<h3>' . esc_html__( 'Oops, no results found, please try again...', 'motors' ) . '</h3>';
    $response['html'] .= '</div>';
    $response['html'] .= '</div>';
endif;
wp_reset_postdata();



$show_pagination = true;
if(!empty($query->found_posts) and !empty($listing->query_vars['posts_per_page'])) {
    if($query->found_posts < $query->query_vars['posts_per_page']) {
        $show_pagination = false;
    }
}

if($show_pagination) {

    $response['pagination'] .= '<div class="col-md-12">';
    $response['pagination'] .= '<div class="clearfix">';
    $response['pagination'] .= '<div class="stm-blog-pagination">';

    $response['pagination'] .= paginate_links( array(
        'base'           => stm_get_listing_archive_link() . '%_%',
        'type'           => 'list',
        'total'          => $query->max_num_pages,
        'posts_per_page' => $query->query_vars['posts_per_page'],
        'prev_text'      => '<i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i>',
        'next_text'      => '<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>',
    ) );

    $response['pagination'] .= '</div>';
    if ( stm_is_motorcycle() ) {
        $response['pagination'] .= '<div class="stm-motorcycle-per-page stm_boats_view_by">';
        ob_start();
        get_template_part( 'partials/listing-layout-parts/items-per', 'page' );
        $response['pagination'] .= ob_get_contents();
        ob_end_clean();
        $response['pagination'] .= '</div>';
    }
    $response['pagination'] .= '</div>';
    $response['pagination'] .= '</div>';
} elseif(stm_is_motorcycle()) {
    $response['pagination'] .= '<div class="stm-motorcycle-per-page stm_boats_view_by left-mode">';
    ob_start();
    get_template_part( 'partials/listing-layout-parts/items-per', 'page' );
    $response['pagination'] .= ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();
    $response['pagination'] .= '</div>';
}


$response = json_encode( $response );

echo $response;
exit;
}
add_action('wp_ajax_stm_ajax_filter_profile' , 'stm_ajax_filter_profile');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_stm_ajax_filter_profile','stm_ajax_filter_profile');
```

This allows me to query all posts by a certain user but I cannot search all the custom parameters from the function above...if I could merge this code with the one above I would have my desired function.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'listings',
    'post_status'    => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'stm_car_user',
            'value' => $user_id
        )
    )
);

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Looks like the query is being created in the stm_get_filter() function. You could try adding the query args there or posting the contents of that function.

Comment: Thank you for that advice! I found the solution within that function.